# Issue with switch statement and $_GET

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

I have an issue with this switch case, I will be glad if someone could give me a hint on what's going wrong.

The lines below keep on adding the case 1, 2 or 3 below the default one (centre_1) instead of replacing it.

I can't find where it goes wrong. Here is the code :

```
<?php include("mx/centre_1.php");
if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page='centre_mx.php';
} else {
    switch($_GET['page']) {
        case'centre_1':
            include('/mx/centre_1.php');
            break;
        case'centre_2':
            include('/mx/centre_2.php');
            break;
        case'centre_3':
            include('/mx/centre_3.php');
            break;
    }
}   
?>
```

Any assistance will be helpful.

Comment: `isset` will check the variable in set or not. But it wont check empty value. So better use `empty`

Comment: Read that first line of code again...

Comment: what are you trying to do? What do you mean by "replace" it?

Comment: "The lines below keep on adding the case 1, 2 or 3 below the default one (centre_1) instead of replacing it." Why do you think they should replace it?

Comment: I wanted the page to display the first case automatically when the page loads, and to display the other cases instead when selected 
(with <a href="?page=centre_3"> for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason '/mx/centre_1.php' is always being displayed is because you have it at the top of your code, outside of the if and switch statement. Due to this it'll be included on every page load.

In order to only have '/mx/centre_1.php' appear when no other option is selected you need to make it the default switch case.

```
   $page = '';
   if(in_array('page', $_GET)) {
      $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    switch($page) {
        case 'centre_2':
            include('/mx/centre_2.php');
            break;
        case 'centre_3':
            include('/mx/centre_3.php');
            break;
        default:
            include('/mx/centre_1.php');
    }
```

The default case in a switch statement will happen when none of the other cases match the variable provided. That is, if $_GET['page'] doesn't equal centre_2 or centre_3 then the default code will be performed.

I'd suggest reading up more on switch statements [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), since you don't seem to understand how they work.